# Parse Error, Expected Pragma on remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am new to remix and can't figure out what is wrong with this basic function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
  contract Pie {
  uint256 public p;
}


function pie () public returns (uint256) {
         uint256 x = p;
         returns x;
         }
```

Comment: Am I missing something super simple like a semi colon somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Lol for people who look at this in the future, the error was simple.

My functions weren't in the contract.

Comment: Thanks for circling back to let us know it's resolved. It might help someone else. You are allowed to accept your own answer if you want.